# Add rows to asp:gridview - taking values from text boxes

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to add the values entered in textboxes to a gridview on the same page.
I am using a button and Event(btn_add_Click) to do this.

I used an IF loop to check the old data of the gridview and I try to maintain it in List.

When I enter data in the text boxes - The row gets added the first time.
But second time - when the Session["dt"] carries data, it enters the IF loop erroring at the typecast of the session variable.

Please suggest as how to type cast the session - or how to maintain the old data of the gridview when adding a new row.

Code--

```
protected void btn_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Member> lstMember = new List<Member>();
        if (Session["dt"] != null)
        {
            lstMember = (List<Member>)Session["dt"];
        }
        Member Member = new Member();

    Member.Name = txt_NameMember.Text;
    Member.Mobile = txt_MobileMem.Text;
    Member.Email = txt_EmailMem.Text;
    Member.Degree = txt_degreeMem.Text;
    Member.Nationality = txt_NatMem.Text;
    Member.Skills = txt_SkillsMem.Text;
    lstMember.Add(new Member(Member));
    gv_memDetails.DataSource = lstMember;
    gv_memDetails.DataBind();
    Session["dt"] = lstMember;
}

public class Member
{
    public Member() { }
    public Member(Member cust)
    {

        Name = cust.Name;
        Mobile = cust.Mobile;
        Email = cust.Email;
        Degree = cust.Degree;
        Nationality = cust.Nationality;
        Skills = cust.Skills;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Degree { get; set; }
    public string Nationality { get; set; }
    public string Skills { get; set; }
```

### }

I checked this link - it has the same typecast. But errors out in my code.

[Add new row data to gridview asp.net c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18681206/add-new-row-data-to-gridview-asp-net-c-sharp)

---

_MY GOAL IS TO ADD A ROW TO GRIDVIEW BY TAKING VALUES FROM TEXTBOXES... PLEASE SUGGEST ANYWAY.... MAY BE A NEW ONE...

Comment: Make sure you are not assigning anything to `Session["dt"]` elsewhere.

Comment: why do you need the old listItems to be kept in session? Simply declare thr List<Member> outside method in class level. In your code every time you add new item you are adding it to new instance of list. And that's what causing the problem. Another thing is without adding the current instance that you initialized taking values from textboxes directly you are adding a new Member(Member) instance in your list, though it'll work, but it makes no sense.

Comment: @afzalulh, I did not assign anything to the session anywhere else... Not sure as to why it still gets reset.

Comment: you can use DataTable also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put [Serializable] before class name:

```
[Serializable]
public class Member
{ ... }
```

then replace

```
Session["dt"]
```

with

```
ViewState["dt"]
```

Comment: This seemed to be good... And I thot I wud have luck with this... But Surprisingly, i got this error - 
**[A]System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Events_AddVolunteer+Member] cannot be cast to [B]System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Events_AddVolunteer+Member]. **

Comment: I dont know y that error.. But yes.. your solution made a great deal.. I am able to add rows and my old data in the gridview is also retained...

Answer (score 0):

What is the error that you are getting? Make sure you are not resetting the session in postback. Try checking if your session is the list of your class:
Like:

```
var data=Session["dt"];
if(data is List<Member>)
{
//your code here
}
```